# How to call a Vue method from main.js in Vue.js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Why am I not able to call my method in App.vue?
Isn't there the div id='App' reference in the App which should make it possible to call methods in there?

*Main.js*

```js
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  methods:{
    gesamt:function () {
       return 'Hello';
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

*App.vue*

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <p>{{gesamt()}}</p>
    <navbar></navbar>
    <ausgaben></ausgaben>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        name:"App",
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You can use `$root.gesamt()` to call the method which is defined in `Main.js`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to add a "global" method to your VueJs app you can add it to Vue itself like this:

```
import {logEngagement} from "./helpers/logEngagement"
Vue.prototype.$logEngagement = logEngagement;
```

you can use it in component.vue like this:

```
<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      this.$logEngagement.log("this");
    }
  }
<script>
```